# Overflow:Hidden -> PHP DIV scroll?

Tags: php, jquery, html, scroll, overflow

So I have a website that navigates by scrolling through a pane of DIVs that's wrapped inside a main DIV via. JQuery/javascript: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

E.g.

```
<div id="content" style:"overflow:hidden; width 800px;">
   <div id="home" class="page"></div>
   <div id="about" class="page"></div>
   <div id="support" class="page"></div>
</div>
```

It navigates and scrolls fine, but attempting to provide dynamic URLs for the pages without breaking the scrolling feature (e.g. mywebsite.com?p=home) brings a bit of trouble.

So depending on what the GET request returns, I want the PHP script to automatically set the scroll position on page load; as the scroll bars are hidden, and can only be set via. javascript.

What is the best method for this?

Comment: Read GET parameter from URL and scroll on load? Or I am misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Yeah. So my website runs off javascript, it looks pretty, but not good for search crawlers and for specific URLs for content (e.g. for social networks; +1, Like and Share buttons). I'm trying to add that functionality without removing javascript features.

Comment: That is true, differend links for same content isn't wise decision. Then use anchors, and read them in javascript, and scroll to requested div. If this is not what you want, then I realy dont understand you ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I use to get the $_GET vars:

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");
    var params = {},
        tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
     }

    return params;
}

var $_GET = getQueryParams(document.location.search);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+$_GET.p).offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that helps me? Depending on the GET data, it will scroll the #content div to the relevant child div. So p=home would show id="home", p=about would show id="about" etc.

Comment: Yes, so you can use the above function to get the "p" param and then scroll to this. I have updated my code to show you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this

```
<script>
    var goTo = '<?php echo (isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : "default_value"); ?>';
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            functionThatScrolls(goTo);
        });
    }(jQuery));
<script>
```

I would do it like this, just print the value of the $_GET['p'] into the script, just make sure to print a default value, and maybe sanitize the value of p someone could insert something into it.

hope it helped.

Comment: This is something I considered, but I don't think it is useful for search engines (I suppose it's the first thing they see), as it will have to flip through some DIVs to get to it's destination.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest simply using plain old [anchor](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12) tags?

The way you've described your site doesn't seem to need all this js magic in order to achieve the effect you're looking for...

```
<div>

  <a name="home">
    <div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a name="pix">
    <div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a name="about us">
    <div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a name="contact">
    <div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Then, links to http://www.mywebsite.com/#home will go do what you're looking for, plus google will index it as a subsection of http://www.mywebsite.com/

I think if you put a `!` before your anchor tag names, google will actually index each as a separate page.

EDIT: Go [here](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html#gc-pagecontent-anchor), and scroll down to "Step-by-step guide".

Comment: This seems like what I need! The javascript is in place to provide a sliding transition from page to page, and to dynamically change link colours and the header image background position (which also has a sliding transition). Right now I have a switch statement for the GET data that sets styling data for the links and background position for the header; I realise they can be set through CSS, where scroll positions cannot. Is there a way for PHP to grab anchor data?

Comment: There is not it seems, but it can be dealt with Javascript which can provide me the desired results or pass it back to PHP.  http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/15/read-the-anchor-part-of-the-url-with-php/